# How to iterate through one item each of the two array per time instead of looping through the complete cycle of dynamic html input in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm having two arrays of fields (id[], names[]) and I want to loop through one item each of the two array per time instead of looping through the complete cycle of id[] before looping through names[] using php

**HTML Code**

```
<input type="text" name="id[]" /> &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="text" name="names[]" /></br>
 <input type="text" name="id[]" /> &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="text" name="nmaes[]" /></br>
 <input type="text" name="id[]" /> &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="text" name="names[]" /></br>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE );
if($_POST['test']=='test')
{
    foreach($_POST['id'] as $key => $value) {
    echo "id $key = $value"."</br>";
}
foreach($_POST['names'] as $key => $value) {
    echo "names $key = $value"."</br>";
}


}

?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count number of element and use it to get your posted data. It's not really nice but that should work.

> Warning, id and name need to be same size!

```
if($_POST['test']=='test')
{
    $count = count($_POST['id']);
    for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
        $id = $_POST['id'][$i];
        $name = $_POST['name'][$i];
        echo "id $i = $id"."</br>";
        echo "name $i = $name"."</br>";
    }
}
```

> Other way

```
if($_POST['test']=='test')
{
    foreach ($_POST['id'] as $i => $id) {
        $name = $_POST['name'][$i];
        echo "id $i = $id"."</br>";
        echo "name $i = $name"."</br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `for` and not just use `$key` from the `foreach`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone ok, i add another way...works as well

Comment: I appreciate the quickness in response. I got the answer using for loop after all night thinking but I prefer your foreach solution. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Glad to help :-D

Comment: @Camille  I appreciate , the for loop is a better option eventually because I had to subtract one from the total post count. So I final used the for instead of the foreach.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this setting `name="user[index][id]"`/`name="user[index][name]` to name of inputs. Index is variable

```
<input type="text" name="user[0][id]"> &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="text" name="user[0][name]"></br>
<input type="text" name="user[1][id]"> &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="text" name="user[1][name]"></br>
<input type="text" name="user[2][id]"> &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="text" name="user[2][name]"></br>
```

And PHP like that

```
<?php
    foreach($_POST['user'] as $user) {
        echo 'id = ' . $user['id'] . '<br> name = ' . $user['name'] . '<br>';
    }
?>
```